# KableExtra table does not work in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

KableExtra functions do not work when I try to create a table in R Markdown (to html).

Here is the demo code that doesn't work in R Markdown:

```
iris %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 10) %>% 
  kbl() %>% 
  kable_styling()
```

The specific error message that shows up is:

```
Error in tempfile("_rs_html_deps_", tmpdir = ctx$outputFolder, fileext = ".json") : 
  temporary name too long
```

The error message shows up when the code is either run in R Markdown (to load the data from the global environment) or when the file is knitted. However, despite the same message showing up when the file is knitted, the table is in the knitted final html document and is correct.

Oddly, the code for the table works correctly when run in the console directly and no error message shows up.

Lastly, I can run this this chunk of code in R Markdown (not knitting) if the table is saved as an object.

```
test = iris %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 10) %>% 
  kbl() %>% 
  kable_styling()
```

However, when I then call `test`, the same error message shows up:

```
Error in tempfile("_rs_html_deps_", tmpdir = ctx$outputFolder, fileext = ".json") : temporary name too long
```

Edit: Added YAML header information

Here is what I have in the YAML header

```
---
title: "Document"
author: "User"
date: "`Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---
```

Edit 2: The problem seems to have gone away after updating R Studio.

Edit 3: Sorry, the problem still persists. Any other ideas?

Comment: I do not have a problem rendering it, how does your yaml (the code between the --- in the beginning of your document) look like?

Comment: Julian - The YAML header information has been added. I don't think it's different from what I usually have.

Comment: I'd guess this message arises because RMarkdown is trying to work in a directory with a very long name.  Does it go away if you move the .Rmd file to a path that has a short name?  Windows has a 260 char limit on path + filename.

Comment: Sorry, I had mentioned that the problem went away. It ended up coming back, and I still can't use kableExtra.

The current path is around 160 characters, so it should be under the 260 character limit.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem here with `kableExtra` version 1.3.4
Chunk code run properly in preview but not rendered in `rmarkdown` for Hugo ink theme.

I strongly believe it is related to the version update. Cause I was able to render it with no problem.

I render it with

```
blogdown::build_site(build_rmd = T, local = T)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I'm not well-versed in kableExtra, so I wasn't able to understand the mechanisms under the hood. What is `blogdown::build_site` for?

When I ran the code you posted, I got:

```Error in site_root() : 
  Could not find config.toml / config.yaml / config/_default/config.toml / config/_default/config.yaml under
   C:/level1/level2/level3/level4/level5
   C:/level1/level2/level3/level4
   C:/level1/level2/level3/
   C:/level1/level2
   C:/level1
   C:/```

Answer (score 0):

In short, the command line [blogdown::built_site](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/methods.html) is one of the methods related to website rendering via bookdown.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).